# What is the best way to transform and visualize data showing changes in object groupings across different parameters?

Tags: python, sql, r, data-science, bioinformatics

I am having some trouble with a data science/bioinformatics problem and I was looking to bounce some ideas off of people. This is my first post, I hope I am asking a question correctly.

I have multiple two-column TSV files, the first column is the name of a gene, and the second column is a family number shared by similar genes:

```
+------+----------+
| Gene | Family # |
+------+----------+
| A    |        1 |
| B    |        1 |
| C    |        1 |
| D    |        2 |
| E    |        2 |
+------+----------+
```

In this case, A B and C are similar, and D and E are similar.

Now, as I change the parameter for similarity to be more stringent, these new groupings occur (another made up example):

```
+------+----------+
| gene | family # |
+------+----------+
| A    | 15       |
| B    | 15       |
| C    | 17       |
| D    | 19       |
| E    | 40       |
| ...  | ...      |
+------+----------+
```

In this case, A and B are similar, but C D and E are all dissimilar.

The family #'s that I have do not have consistent family numbers, so even if they are considered in the same family across different parameters, the family #'s are different.

I want to be able to see how family groups are affected across these different parameters. I have 10 different parameters to test, meaning I want to see how family groupings change across 10 TSV files.

Any idea what is the most efficient way to look at groups? Maybe replacing family #'s with gene names directly like below could work, since family #'s aren't consistent but gene names are:

```
+------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----+
| gene | similar gene #1 | similar gene 2 | similar gene x | ... |
+------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----+
| A    | B               | C              |                | ... |
| B    | A               | C              |                | ... |
| C    | A               | B              |                | ... |
| D    |                 |                |                | ... |
| E    |                 |                |                | ... |
+------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-----+
```

So under a specific parameter, A B and C are still similar, but D and E are not similar to anything else.

I would transform all 10 TSV files to stop using "family #" and replace with "similar genes". Would this be a good idea?

Maybe parsing these TSVs as R dataframes or importing them into SQL datasets could work? The end goal would be to visualize these networks and how these networks change across parameters. The biggest problem that is stopping me right now is that the family numbers are not consistent across different parameters.

Any help or discussion would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you elaborate on "the family numbers do not have consistent family numbers"? I understand that the family number changes when you tighten up some filter or threshold value. What do you mean by "across different parameters". Are these other columns in the DataFrame?

Comment: Apologies! I meant to say that family numbers are not consistent across different parameters. For example, under one set of parameters, the family number that signifies A and B to be similar can be 3. Under a different set of parameters, the family number could be totally different even if the groupings are exactly the same.

Comment: So the groupings _can be_ the same, even with different family numbers. But this doesn't necessarily mean they are guaranteed to be the same, right? You can have A1 B1 C2 and A45 B45 C85 and A67 B22 C22

Comment: Yes, depending on the stringency of similarity, they can differ in groupings. Both the numbers that signify groups, and the groups themselves, can change under different parameters.

Comment: Just in case this suggestion can help: If you recode your family identifiers into Python sets of genes or into sums of powers of 2 (each gene corresponding to a distinct power of 2), you can compare families in terms of set inclusion or intersection (using set operations or bitwise number comparisons).